# How Can I Program an LED Matrix

Tags: led, matrix

I got this really cool idea the other day. Sitting in my Computer-Sci Lab at school I saw the binary clock on the wall. As a "watch guy", I immediately wanted a watch like it. I've always had a DIY attitude, so I looked in to it, and I was wondering:

How can I program an LED Matrix? I know I would have to use some kind of arduino, but I am very unfamiliar with all the lingo. I was wondering if there is some kind of set up that allows me to program one of these in a way similar to programming a computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hack a day has a list of all kind of similar projects. Many of them you could clone and make it your own:

http://hackaday.com/category/led-hacks/